# how to import csv into sqlite table (also when multiple data bases are connected to specific db and table)?

Tags: sqlite, csv

For some reason the CSV file isn't imported to my database file:

```
sqlite> attach '/tmp/databases/d1.db' as d1;
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import '/tmp/1.csv' products
sqlite> .tables
products << not imported into my d1 database

sqlite> .databases
main: 
d1: /tmp/databases/d1.db
```

I've tried the variation:

```
sqlite> .import '/tmp/1.csv' d1.products
Error: no such table: d1.products
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this `.import` command, the `sqlite3` command-line shell will execute the following statements:

```
SELECT * FROM d1.products              -- to check if the table exists
CREATE TABLE d1.products(...)
INSERT INTO "d1.products" VALUES(...)  -- this fails
```

This inconsistent quoting obviously is a bug.

To work around this, open `db1.db` as the main database.

Comment: how do i open db1.db as the main database after I have opened several dbs?

Comment: Use `.open`, or restart `sqlite3`.